# using azure mobile services with MVC application

Tags: c#, ajax, azure, model-view-controller

I need to interact with my Azure Mobile API. Upon login I get an authentication token that is sent with every request. Adding Azure Mobile services to my MVC causes Html helpers to stop working.

How can I get around this? if it is not possible, can someone show me how to add an Header to an AJAX request for a Azure Mobile API request? And is it possible to pass the server response to my controller?

accessing the database without the API is not really a option. I have a client Xamarin Application that uses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I manage to work around my solution.

this link helped: http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2014/04/29/consuming-azure-mobile-service-custom-api-with-net-backend.aspx

so basically this is how it works: Azure mobile library breaks any MVC project so it was uninstalled.

Include: `Newtonsoft.Json` this class is needed to map your response objects to whatever your classes look like.

Keep an close eye to what your uri looks like. Usually is something like https://Your-API-link.net/api/controller (remember that get requests have values added as part of the link and post as part of the header)
 I used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>` for the response mapping